# Can't find the fix for: takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, maya

I got into python recently and I already got stuck with 'takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)' problem.

I've searched for it around and most of the time and read about missing to add the self part.

Despite adding that I can't solve it, am I missing wome important point?

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

class ButtonPress:

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0

    def buildUI(self):
        window = cmds.window(title = 'Press Button', w = 100, h = 50)
        columnL = cmds.columnLayout(w = 100, h = 50)
        cmds.button(parent = columnL, label = 'Press me', w = 100, h = 50, command = self.__increaseAndPrint)
        cmds.showWindow(window)

    def __increaseAndPrint(self):
        self.value += 1
        print self.value
```

Thanks for the help.

EDIT:
I use the class in maya's script editor with:

ButtonPress().buildUI()

And I get:
Error: __increaseAndPrint() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
When pressing the UI button.

Sorry.

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: You forgot to tell us where the error occurred.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maya Python: takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589764/maya-python-takes-exactly-1-argument-2-given)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

class ButtonPress:

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0

    def buildUI(self):
        window = cmds.window(title = 'Press Button', w = 100, h = 50)
        columnL = cmds.columnLayout(w = 100, h = 50)
        cmds.button(parent = columnL, label = 'Press me', w = 100, h = 50, command = self.__increaseAndPrint)
        cmds.showWindow(window)

    def __increaseAndPrint(self, *args):
        # maya throwing through ui a default bool argument as last.
        # you need *args to catch and dismissed it
        self.value += 1
        print self.value
```